# Redim size of array in VBA Excel

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have some problem to use the function `redim` preserve in VBA Excel.

I would like to `redim` an array I already use in the macro before without clear the data already inside.

My macro is looking like that :

```
Dim table_data As Variant
...
ReDim table_data(2 * n + 2 * m + 2 * n, table_case.ListColumns.Count - 1)
...
dim1 = UBound(table_data, 1)
dim2 = UBound(table_data, 2)
ReDim Preserve table_data(0 To dim1 + 2 * n, 0 To dim2)
```

Do you have any idea what I should modify?

Comment: What is the problem? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Only the last dimension can be changed, unfortunately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using `Preserve` keyword; you can change size only for the last dimension. The size of other dimensions once declared must remain unaltered.

The code below should work:

```
ReDim Preserve table_data(LBound(table_data, 1) To UBound(table_data, 1), 0 To dim2)
```